# Нужна ли запятая перед сравнительным оборотом?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая перед сравнительным оборотом: окутала мой разум, точно
простыней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень важно **приводить предложение полностью, а не фрагментами**, так как постановка знаков препинания зависит от структуры всего предложения, а иногда и от контекста.

*Я сейчас курю восхитительную мысль с обаятельным запахом. **Ее смолистая нега окутала мой разум точно простыней**.*
[**Афоризмы от Велимира Хлебникова**](http://stuki-druki.com/Aforizmi-Khlebnikov_Velimir.php)

Запятой здесь нет, оборот с союзом ТОЧНО имеет значение уподобления, а в этом случае обособление факультативно, в том числе зависит от структуры предложения. В данном случае паузы нет, ударение падает на оборот.

Answer (score 1):

**Запятая перед сравнительным оборотом нужна**: *окутала мой разум, точно 
простынёй.*

Сравнительные обороты с союзами БУДТО, ТОЧНО, СЛОВНО, НЕЖЕЛИ и др. на письме выделяются запятыми. [Сравнительный оборот](http://raal100.narod.ru/index/0-50)

Comment: Если не указать союз КАК, то следующий вопрос от Василисы будет об оборотах с ним.